# Configure WildFly to use HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, java, wildfly

I am using WildFly25, and have it running with default settings.

**Server console**

```
WildFly Full 25.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 17.0.1.Final) started in 3938ms - Started 308 of 547 services (338 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

I want to update the config, so it runs using SSL/TLS on https.

So I follow the WildFly [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Using%20the%20Elytron%20Subsystem.html#110231569_UsingtheElytronSubsystem-EnableOnewaySSL%2FTLSforApplications) to configure it using the WildFly CLI (advise is to use the CLI and not to edit the XML manually because there is less chance for errors).

**Configuration**

Connect via the CLI:

```
/home/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/bin ./jboss-cli.sh
connect
```

I have a keystore (`mykeystore.jks`). So then I add the keystore to the WildFly config:

```
/subsystem=elytron/key-store=httpsKS:add(path=/home/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mykeystore.jks,credential-reference={clear-text=password},type=JKS)

/subsystem=elytron/key-manager=httpsKM:add(key-store=httpsKS,credential-reference={clear-text=password})
/subsystem=elytron/server-ssl-context=httpsSSC:add(key-manager=httpsKM,protocols=["TLSv1.2"])
```

When I check the `security-realm`:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:read-attribute(name=security-realm)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => undefined
}
```

This is visible in **standalone.xml**:

```
        <tls>
            <key-stores>
                <key-store name="applicationKS">
                    <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                    <implementation type="JKS"/>
                    <file path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </key-store>
                <key-store name="httpsKS">
                    <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                    <implementation type="JKS"/>
                    <file path="/home/jboss/wildfly/wildfly-25.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/mykeystore.jks"/>
                </key-store>
            </key-stores>
            <key-managers>
                <key-manager name="applicationKM" key-store="applicationKS" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost">
                    <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                </key-manager>
                <key-manager name="httpsKM" key-store="httpsKS">
                    <credential-reference clear-text="password"/>
                </key-manager>
            </key-managers>
            <server-ssl-contexts>
                <server-ssl-context name="applicationSSC" key-manager="applicationKM"/>
                <server-ssl-context name="httpsSSC" protocols="TLSv1.2" key-manager="httpsKM"/>
            </server-ssl-contexts>
        </tls>
```

But I don't see any `<security-realm>` in the xml:

```
        <security-realms>
            <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
            <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </properties-realm>
            <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </properties-realm>
        </security-realms>
```

As the `security-realm` is `undefined` (before and after any changes), I run the following (from the WildFly [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Using%20the%20Elytron%20Subsystem.html#110231569_UsingtheElytronSubsystem-EnableOnewaySSL%2FTLSforApplications)), but it has no affect. (this looks like it sets the `security-realm` to `undefined` so it should not have any affect to an already `undefined` `security-realm`).

```
batch
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:undefine-attribute(name=security-realm)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=ssl-context,value=httpsSSC)
run-batch

reload
```

**Question**

What am I missing?  After following the WildFly documentation, I would expect to have the following (i.e. the server listening for the management console on `https` and port `9993`):

**Server console**

```
WildFly Full 25.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 17.0.1.Final) started in 3938ms - Started 308 of 547 services (338 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Http management interface listening on https://127.0.0.1:9993/management
Admin console listening on https://127.0.0.1:9993
```

**More info**

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface:write-attribute(name=secure-socket-binding, value=management-https)
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYSRV0259: If attribute secure-socket-binding is defined ssl-context must also be defined",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this it started to work:

```
/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface:write-attribute(name=ssl-context,value=httpsSSC)
reload
/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface:write-attribute(name=secure-socket-binding, value=management-https)
reload
```

console output:

```
09:25:59,234 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0062: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management and https://127.0.0.1:9993/management
09:25:59,234 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0053: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990 and https://127.0.0.1:9993
```